# A for-loop to iterate over an enum in Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, enums

I have an `enum` in Java for the cardinal and intermediate directions:

```
public enum Direction {
   NORTH,
   NORTHEAST,
   EAST,
   SOUTHEAST,
   SOUTH,
   SOUTHWEST,
   WEST,
   NORTHWEST
}
```

How can I write a `for` loop that iterates through each of these `enum` values?

Comment: Java 8 : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30962181/1216775

Answer (score 1489, accepted):

## `.values()`

You can call the `values()` method on your enum.

```
for (Direction dir : Direction.values()) {
  // do what you want
}
```

This `values()` method is [implicitly declared by the compiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.3). So it is not listed on [`Enum`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) doc.

Comment: Why this method *values()* isn't listed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) under java.lang.enum

Comment: @jacktrades: It is an implicit method that exists only in the compiler. Therefore the base class can not declare a method with the same name and thus it does not get included in the automatically generated Javadocs.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.2

Comment: Oddly, it is mentioned in the [valueOf() docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String))

Answer (score 142):

All the constants of an enum type can be obtained by calling the implicit `public static T[] values()` method of that type:

```
 for (Direction d : Direction.values()) {
     System.out.println(d);
 }
```

Comment: @RAnders00 True. But still the answer is valid and the format really doesn't matter (atleast to me)

Comment: What does the `#` do?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Basically it's saying that values() is part of the Enum object. e.g `Enum#values()` = `Enum.values()`

Comment: Hmm, I'm sorry, I don't follow, is it the same as using `.` (always?)?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD The hashtag is JavaDoc syntax, not Java code.

Answer (score 65):

You can do this as follows:

```
for (Direction direction : EnumSet.allOf(Direction.class)) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Provided you import java.util.EnumSet

Comment: Super useful for Java8 foreach loops.

EnumSet.allOf(Enum.class).forEach(blah -> method(blah))

Comment: @Hiro2k You could also do `Arrays.stream(Enum.values()).forEach(...)` - the stream will be sequential

Comment: Can you explain why it's better than `Enum.values()` ?

Comment: @schatten well, it's a `set` instead of `array`. It's not "better", although it describes enum values better in my opinion, because from set's definition, values in set cannot be repeated (like in enum), whereas values in array can be.

Comment: @Jezor It's a better choice when you actually need a very fast set of enums, like bit flags, though seems to be too complicated for a simple iteration.

Answer (score 47):

## Streams

### Prior to Java 8

```
for (Direction dir : Direction.values()) {
            System.out.println(dir);
}
```

### Java 8

We can also make use of lambda and streams ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)):

```
Stream.of(Direction.values()).forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

---

**Why `forEachOrdered` and not `forEach` with streams ?**

The behaviour of `forEach` is explicitly nondeterministic where as the `forEachOrdered` performs an action for each element of this stream, in the encounter order of the stream if the stream has a defined encounter order. So `forEach` does not guarantee that the order would be kept.

Also when working with streams (especially parallel ones) keep in mind the nature of streams. As per the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

Stream pipeline results may be nondeterministic or incorrect if the behavioral parameters to the stream operations are stateful. A stateful lambda is one whose result depends on any state which might change during the execution of the stream pipeline.

```
Set<Integer> seen = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<>());
stream.parallel().map(e -> { if (seen.add(e)) return 0; else return e; })...
```

Here, if the mapping operation is performed in parallel, the results for the same input could vary from run to run, due to thread scheduling differences, whereas, with a stateless lambda expression the results would always be the same.

Side-effects in behavioral parameters to stream operations are, in general, discouraged, as they can often lead to unwitting violations of the statelessness requirement, as well as other thread-safety hazards.

Streams may or may not have a defined encounter order. Whether or not a stream has an encounter order depends on the source and the intermediate operations.

Comment: As with all stream operations be aware of thread statelessness and side effect limits https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness.  These 2 enum iteration options are significantly different in this regard.

Comment: For most use cases there is no advantage to replace a simple loop with lambda and streams.

Answer (score 21):

If you don't care about the order this should work:

```
Set<Direction> directions = EnumSet.allOf(Direction.class);
for(Direction direction : directions) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Provided you import java.util.EnumSet and java.util.Set

Comment: From the [documentation for `EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html): *The iterator returned by the iterator method traverses the elements in their **natural order** (the order in which the enum constants are declared)*.  This guarantees that the order of iteration matches the order returned by `Enum.values()`.

Answer (score 7):

Java8

```
Stream.of(Direction.values()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

from Java5+

```
for ( Direction d: Direction.values()){
 System.out.println(d);
}
```

Comment: oh sorry. I just realized that akhil_mittal already posted the similar answer.

Comment: When and why should I use Stream.of(o).forEach? The for loop seems much more readable.

Comment: Not if you are familiar with functional programming.

Answer (score 5):

More methods in java 8:

### Using `EnumSet` with `forEach`

```
EnumSet.allOf(Direction.class).forEach(...);
```

### Using `Arrays.asList` with `forEach`

```
Arrays.asList(Direction.values()).forEach(...);
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use a filter (JAVA 8) like this.

```java
Stream.of(Direction.values()).filter(name -> !name.toString().startsWith("S")).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Scenario**: Let's say, we have a fixed number of card types.
Each card type has fees and a joining bonus associated with it.

```
package enumPkg;

public enum CardTypes {
//Each enum is object
DEBIT(10,20),
CREDIT(0,10),
CRYPTO(5,30);

//Object properties
int fees;
int bonus;

//Initilize object using constructor
CardTypes(int fee, int bonus){
    this.fees = fee;
    this.bonus = bonus;
}

//access object property
public int getFees(){
    return this.fees;
}

public int getBonus(){
    return this.bonus;
}

}
```

Now to access enum in other class. Follow the below process in java:

```
package enumPkg;

public class EnumClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CardTypes cardType = CardTypes.CREDIT; //Each enum element is public static final, when accessed returns a object
    System.out.println(cardType);

    System.out.println("Debit card fees : "+CardTypes.DEBIT.getFees());
    System.out.println("Debit card bonus : "+CardTypes.DEBIT.getBonus());

    CardTypes[] cardTypes = CardTypes.values();//return array of CardTypes i.e all enum elements we have defined

    for (CardTypes type : CardTypes.values()) {
        System.out.println(type); //particular enum object
        System.out.println(type.ordinal()); //return enum position
        System.out.println("Bonus : "+type.getBonus()); //return enum object property: Bonus
        System.out.println("Fees  : "+type.getFees());//return enum object property: Fees
    }

}
}
```

Output:

```
CREDIT
Debit card fees : 10
Debit card bonus : 20
DEBIT
0
Bonus : 20
Fees  : 10
CREDIT
1
Bonus : 10
Fees  : 0
CRYPTO
2
Bonus : 30
Fees  : 5
```