# How do I loop through an enum in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop, enums

Let's say I have an enum like so:

```
public enum Numbers {
    ONE("Uno "),
    TWO("Dos "),
    THREE("Tres ");
}

private final String spanishName;

Numbers(String spanishName) {
    this.spanishName = spanishName;
}

public String getSpanishName() {
    return spanishName;
}
```

Now I have a method that outputs a given variable.

```
public void output(String value) {
    printStream.print(value);
}
```

I want to use a `for` loop to output all the values in the enum. Something along the lines of this:

```
for(/*each element in the enum*/) {
    //output the corresponding spanish name
}
```

Ultimate I want the final output to be `Uno Dos Tres`. How can I do this using enums and a for loop?

Comment: @RaviThapliyal You won't find '.values()' under Enum in the JavaDocs. It's an implicit method for enum type.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
for (Numbers n : Numbers.values()) {
   System.out.print(n.getSpanishName() + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use this:

```
for (Numbers d : Numbers .values()) {
     System.out.println(d);
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
for (Numbers num : Numbers.values()) {
  // do what you want
}
```

looks like duplicate:
[A 'for' loop to iterate over an enum in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104975/for-loop-to-iterate-over-enum-in-java)