# What is a compiler implicit method?

Tags: java, enums

A comment to this question : [A 'for' loop to iterate over an enum in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104975/for-loop-to-iterate-over-enum-in-java) states :

> @jacktrades: It is an implicit method that exists only in the
>   compiler. Therefore the base class can not declare a method with the
>   same name and thus it does not get included in the automatically
>   generated Javadocs.
>   docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.2 – 
>   Torben Mar 5 at 9:32

Since this method only exists in the compiler does this mean it existed before the Enum object becames available in jdk1.5 ? Does this method exist for other objects that are compiler only. java.util.Map contains a values() method but this is documented and so is explicit ? Why define this method .values as implicit, this is a useful method on Enum types so it should be explicit and available on the Enum object type ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Since this method only exists in the compiler does this mean it existed before the Enum object becames available in jdk1.5 ?**

No, it was added for Java 5.

**Does this method exist for other objects that are compiler only. java.util.Map contains a values() method but this is documented and so is explicit ?**

That's different.  `Map.values()` is a normal method, part of the `Map` interface.  For any enum type, values() is a static method.  The key difference is that static methods are not inherited, so adding `values()` to java.lang.Enum would not have helped.  Another implicit method is `[EnumType].valueOf(String name)`.

**Why define this method .values as implicit, this is a useful method on Enum types so it should be explicit ?**

Again, there's no way it could be explicit, since static methods are not inherited.  For `valueOf` there's an analog `valueOf(class<T> type, name)` method in `java.lang.Enum`.  I'm not sure why there is no `values(class<T> type)` in there; it would've made sense to me. But instead there is `Class.getEnumConstants()`, which does the same thing.

Comment: There is a `Class.getEnumConstants()`.