# Looping through "Color" enum and printing values. Different ways of doing it

Tags: java, enums

I found 3 (rather 2.5) ways of getting all the values from an `enum`. I have an `enum Color` and I'm trying to iterate over its values. Here are my 3 ways:

---

```
Color[] colors;
colors = Color.class.getEnumConstants();
System.out.println(colors[0]);
```

Gives: NP, not sure why.

---

```
Set<Color> colorSet = EnumSet.allOf(Color.class);  
Iterator<Color> colorIterator = colorSet.iterator();  
while (colorIterator.hasNext()) {  
    Color color = colorIterator.next();
    System.out.println(color);
}
```

Gives:

> Bound mismatch: The generic method `allOf(Class<E>)` of type `EnumSet<E>` is not applicable for the arguments `(Class<Color>)`. The inferred type Color is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter `<E extends Enum<E>>`

---

```
Color[] colors2 = Color.values();  
for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {  
    Color c = colors[i];
```

Gives:

> The method values() is undefined for the type Color.

---

Please explain all these cases. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104975/for-loop-to-iterate-over-enum-in-java) on how to iterate over `enum` values.

Comment: All three of these errors suggest `Color` is not a proper `enum` type.  Please post the definition of `Color`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman The OP is probably talking about `java.awt.Color` which is not a proper `enum` type as you suspected. It simply contains several static fields that refer to pre-defined colors.

Comment: @MikeB yes, you are right. So then the question becomes - how do I get all the values from java.awt.Color then?

Comment: Show the definition of `Color`

Comment: @MindaugasBernatavičius You'd have to use reflection to do it. You could look for all `static Color` fields in the class.

Comment: You can get all the values from here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html.

Comment: Ok, so basically aw.Color is not a proper enum, hence all these errors, correct? Now the only way to get all the values static fields from the class is to use Reflection, correct? Any guidence on this if so?

Comment: @BheshGurung I believe the OP wants access to the values programmatically. Can't iterate over a javadoc :(

Comment: @MindaugasBernatavičius Tutorial on checking the type of fields: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldTypes.html and one on checking the modifiers of fields: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldModifiers.html

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
Field[] fieldArray = Color.class.getDeclaredFields();

for (Field field : fieldArray ) {
    if (java.lang.reflect.Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers())) {
        System.out.println(field);
    }
}
```

You will also need to import:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.awt.Color;
```

Running it, it outputs lengthly strings; however, you could easily just parse the end bit off them.

They look like:

```
public static final java.awt.Color java.awt.Color.WHITE
```

Comment: Not at a computer with a Java IDE? No problem! http://www.compileonline.com/compile_java_online.php

Comment: Cool, I never knew about that!

Comment: Very useful, and the site supports a number of different languages, from LOLCODE to C.

Comment: This is a good solution. Furthermore, if you just want the colour names you can use field.getType() to check they are Colors and field.getName() to get the name. So "public static final java.awt.Color java.awt.Color.WHITE" would be "WHITE".

Answer (score 2):

In the comments on the question, OP reveals this is actually about `java.awt.Color`. So:

```
Class clazz = Color.class;
Field[] colorFields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
Field firstColorField = colorFields[0];
Color firstColor = (Color)firstColorField.get(null);
```

You can iterate over `colorFields` to get each of the colors in `Color`. Note: `Color` has upper- and lower-case versions of the same RGB value, so you may want to keep track of the colors you've found and compare new ones to the already-seen colors, so as not to produce duplicates (if that's what you want). `firstColorField.getName()` will also tell you the name of the field.

Here's a sample that prints the name and value of each of the colors once:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class PrintColors
{
    public static void main(String []args) throws IllegalAccessException
    {
        Class clazz = Color.class;
        Field[] colorFields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();

        HashMap<String, Color> singleColors = new HashMap<String, Color>();
        for (Field cf : colorFields)
        {
            int modifiers = cf.getModifiers();
            if (!Modifier.isPublic(modifiers)) continue;

            Color c = (Color)cf.get(null);
            if (!singleColors.values().contains(c))
                singleColors.put(cf.getName(), c);
        }

        for (String k : singleColors.keySet())
        {
            System.out.println(k + ": " + singleColors.get(k));
        }
    }
}
```