# Regex for Checking Variable-Name in Java to eliminate many IF-ELSE Blocks

Tags: java, json, enums

```
enum MYOPTIONS {
   OPTION1,OPTION2,OPTION3 .....OPTION100
}

class test {
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
   public void checkAndAddEnumToList(){
    if(listA.contain(MYOPTIONS.OPTION1.toString())){
 map.add(MYOPTIONS.OPTION1.toString(),obj.getJSONArray(MYOPTIONS.OPTION1.toString()));
   } else if(listA.contain(MYOPTIONS.OPTION2.toString())){
       map.add(MYOPTIONS.OPTION2.toString(),obj.getJSONArray(MYOPTIONS.OPTION2.toString()));
   }else if(listA.contain(MYOPTIONS.OPTION3.toString())){
      map.add(MYOPTIONS.OPTION3.toString(),obj.getJSONArray(MYOPTIONS.OPTION3.toString()));
   }
  }
}
```

I have OPTION1 to OPTION100, Anyway to avoid If-Else and use REGEX with Loop? 
Above is just a sample. I am looking to replace IF-ELSE with regex

Comment: `for` option 1 to 100?

Comment: yes. I dont want 100 IF-ELSE blocks
If condition based on OPTION{1-100} and setValue also same OPTION{1-100}

Comment: seems like it would be much easier to have an ArrayList of options and iterate through that, and adding the "found" element from list A to list B

Comment: You should iterate `MYOPTIONS.values()`.  Though it would probably be more efficient to actually iterate `listA`, parse each value with `MYOPTIONS.valueOf()`, and add it if the parse succeeded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A for loop to iterate over an enum in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104975/a-for-loop-to-iterate-over-an-enum-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

For enums you can use `valueOf()` and in Java 8+ use streams (or iterate through the list).

```
public List<MYOPTIONS> checkAndAddEnumToList(List<String> listA) {
    List<Enums.ProfileVisibility> listB = new ArrayList<>();
    listA.stream().forEach(i -> listB.add(Enums.ProfileVisibility.valueOf(i)));
    return listB;
}
```